# Where to use additional condition when using Array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I was trying to solve the following question:

> Write a function that returns true if all array elements are true. Use reduce

The is the solution I made up

```js
function allTrue(values) {
  if ( values[0] === false) return false
  if (values.length === 0) return true
  let result = values.reduce( (final, value) => final = value === true, true) 
  return result ? true : false
}
```

My question is, whether it is possible to move the external conditions into the reduce method's body or not.

In other words, if I was required to use a single reduce method to solve it, can I implement it?

I tried manipulating the **final** in the reduce, but it is modified later in next iterations

For instance the following test should return *false* but returns true

```js
allTrue([false, true])
```

Any explanation would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: is `reduce` must ? if not why can't use `every` method which makes life easier :)

Comment: @Codenewbie that's probably a homework, so yes, even if `every` is better they still should use `reduce`, just to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the `reduce` only returns the result of the comparison of the *last* element in the array with `true`. Since the last element in `[false, true]` is `true`, it returns `true`.

Note that your code is overly complex, you have already effectively included your conditions in the `reduce` (giving an initial value of `true` means that a zero-length array will return `true`). Your one issue is that the code in the `reduce` is incorrect, you should be checking whether *all* the previous values are `true` as well as the current one by and'ing the current value with the and of all the previous values:

```js
const allTrue = (values) => values.reduce((curr, value) => curr && value, true);

console.log(allTrue([]));
console.log(allTrue([true]));
console.log(allTrue([false]));
console.log(allTrue([true, true, true]));
console.log(allTrue([false, true]));
```

Comment: Nice handling of empty arrays 

Comment: @Nick
I get the codes to work but I have difficulty writing them as simple as yours.
Does flow-charting help with that? Thanks

Comment: @Nader.Bhr a lot of it really comes down to experience and having solved similar problems before.

Comment: Just from a *code golf* perspective, you can remove those parentheses...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado true, but then I wouldn't name my variables `values`, `curr` and `value` either... :-)

Comment: @Nick

Is it fine in the stackoverflow to post the challenges I am trying to solve and ask for best practices?
Note: I mean the questions that I have already solved, not looking for solutions

Comment: @Nader.Bhr generally, no. SO is for solving problems with code. Questions like that are typically better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com but be sure to read the tour there to make sure your question is appropriate before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be help:

```js
function allTrue(values) {
  return values.reduce((final, value) => final && value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `every` as well to find the solution to this. Below is the snippet for both `every` as well as `reduce`

```js
var allTrue_Every = (arr) => arr.every(d => d == true)

console.log(allTrue_Every([true, true]))
console.log(allTrue_Every([true, false]))

var allTrue_Reduce = (arr) => arr.reduce((r, d) => r && d, true)


console.log(allTrue_Reduce([true, true]))
console.log(allTrue_Reduce([true, false]))
```